# Exception with transacted set on activemq endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I would like to understand why I would be getting the following exception when "transacted" is set on a route.

```
 errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("activemq:EXCEPTION")
                .useOriginalMessage()
                .maximumRedeliveries(1));

 from("activemq:TRIGGER").routeId("Trigger")
                .transacted()
                .bean("helloService")
                .to("log:out");
```

I would like for any exceptions that are being thrown to be sent to an EXCEPTION queue.  It is my understanding that "transacted" needs to be set to make the route a transaction.  When I remove the configuration I don't get the exception below.

Exception is created when string for Hello class is set to larger then 5 characters.

Example code:
https://github.com/zachariahyoung/docker-camel

```
2015-12-03 21:59:26.706  WARN 9900 --- [nsumer[TRIGGER]] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 22001, SQLState: 22001
2015-12-03 21:59:26.706 ERROR 9900 --- [nsumer[TRIGGER]] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Value too long for column "TEXT VARCHAR(5)": "'sdsfasdfasdf' (12)"; SQL statement:
insert into hello (id, text) values (null, ?) [22001-190]
2015-12-03 21:59:26.707  WARN 9900 --- [nsumer[TRIGGER]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction rollback (0x7e2bd5e6) redelivered(true) for (MessageId: ID:CHARLA-49686-1449193952655-71:1:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-CHARLA-63325-1449200820961-0-37) caught: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
2015-12-03 21:59:26.708  WARN 9900 --- [nsumer[TRIGGER]] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly]

org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1642) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:186) ~[camel-jms-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:107) ~[camel-jms-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651) ~[spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:233) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1039) [spring-jms-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:174) ~[camel-spring-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:134) ~[camel-spring-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:103) ~[camel-spring-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:112) ~[camel-spring-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103) ~[camel-jms-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is thrown because camel is propagating rollback. If you call this route from another, camel will rollback that route too. You must catch exception which marked route as rollback and tell camel to only mark this route as rollback. Before `.transacted()` add:

```
.onException(Exception.class).markRollbackOnlyLast().end()
```

Comment: So that handles the exception but now it's not routing back to the deadLetterChannel.  Why can't I add markRollbackOnlyLast on errorHandler class?

Comment: or add `.handled(false)` after `.onException(Exception.class)`:
`.onException(Exception.class).handled(false).mark...`